# How to change color of the currently active window in Blender?

Tags: theme

I would love to change the highlight color of the window being used when working in Blender. Now, when I hover over it, it highlights just a tiny bit. Is it possible to highlight it with different color or at lest more of the white highlight that it currently uses? I wasnt able to find the proper setting for it in Settings - Themes..
[image]

Thank you!
Martin

Comment: I don't think there exists any parameter to change highlight appearance at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your theme using `Edit` > `Preferences` > `Themes`.  From there, go to each panel, then open the `Theme space` dropdown, and set the `Header` colour:

[image: Header colour]

You'll have to do this for each menu, I don't think there's a setting for all the menus.

Theme docs: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/themes.html

Comment: Mmm... Hot pink

Comment: Thank you, this helps, however, I was more after editting the effect where if you hover over the Header, it highlights a little. But it highlights only.. very little. It would be great to see the highlight more clearly or in different color :-)

Comment: You have asked a hard thing! I think it's actually dulling them down when _not_ hovered.  Have you seen this? https://blenderartists.org/t/changing-the-color-of-the-window-header-that-the-mouse-is-hovering-over/637054/9